# Defino um valor em uma classe, quando instancio a mesma o valor é outro

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Este é o código onde defini uma classe `Animal` e um método criador que pergunta a espécie do animal e define seu estado como vivo:

```
        public class Animal
    {
        public bool estaVivo, usaDrogas = false;
        string Especie;
        public Animal()
        {
            bool estaVivo = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Qual a espécie desse animal?");
            Especie = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(estaVivo);//debug
        }
```

Em seguido, tenho a classe doméstico, que herda de Animal

```
  public class Domestic : Animal
  {
        public Domestico()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Qual o nome do seu bicho de estimação?");
            Nome = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Qual a idade do seu bicho de estimação? (NUMERIC)");
            Idade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
  }
```

Finalmente o método principal onde instancio o objeto:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Domestico bicho = new Domestico();

        Console.WriteLine(bicho.estaVivo);//debug


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

A questão é, porquê quando o método construtor da classe `Animal` é chamado o valor de esta vivo é `True`, como pretendido, porém quando instancio a classe derivada `Domestico` o valor se torna `False` (e além disso não consigo alterar seu valor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você declarou o membro da classe `Animal` como `bool` e como não colocou valor algum para ele, o valor *default* deste tipo é `false`. Então não tem nada errado.

Certamente sua intenção não era esta. E pensa que inicializou este membro dentro do construtor. Mas não fez isto.

Dentro do construtor foi declarada uma variável local com o mesmo nome e tipo e foi atribuído um valor `true` para ela. A variável não foi usada e descartada (até foi usada para *debugar*, mas não é o normal do método).

A melhor solução é não declarar a variável, ou seja, basta tirar o tipo dela e estará atribuindo o valor para o membro e não para uma variável local.

Se quiser ser explícito e evitar confusão use `this.estaVivo`. Assim garante que está se referindo inequivocamente ao membro da classe e não à variável - que nem deveria existir no método.

```
public class Animal {
    public bool estaVivo, usaDrogas = false;
    string Especie;
    public Animal() {
        estaVivo = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Qual a espécie desse animal?");
        Especie = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(estaVivo);//debug
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UIBWqO). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4fUGIE). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/InstanceProblem.cs).

Note que se você tivesse inicializado o membro com `true` - e neste caso acho que deveria ter feito - nem precisava fazer isto no construtor. Pra falar a verdade esta classe [não deveria ter um construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). A única coisa que o construtor está fazendo, não deveria ser dentro de um construtor. Talvez não deveria ser nem dentro desta classe, se quiser desenhar [classes do jeito certo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UBLOaE).

Comment: Funcionou bem, não tinha notado que eu tinha declarado a variável dentro do construtor. Afinal, eu já tinha visto sua resposta sobre a utilização de construtores, foi aí que resolvi fazer esse teste, para descobrir como um construtor funciona em C#.
Além disso, acabei aprendendo a usar a palavra-chave `this`.

Comment: O `this` é muito mais que isto mas a principal funcionalidade dele é desambiguar variáveis de instância das locais.

Answer (score 0):

Você esta sobrescrevendo o construtor, e o valor default é false

```
    public Domestico()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Qual o nome do seu bicho de estimação?");
        Nome = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Qual a idade do seu bicho de estimação? (NUMERIC)");
        Idade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //Nesse bloco voce sobrescreveu o construtor da classe pai.
    }
```

Comment: Na verdade, não, até porque o meu programa está exatamente como postei aqui... O erro, assim como apontado por @bigown é que eu declarei a variável `estaVivo` novamente dentro do construtor.